# maintaining two table structures the same on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

We have two tables A and B in PostgreSQL 9.4. We want to ensure that A's columns are always a subset of the columns of B (that is, preventing an `ALTER` on A from adding/dropping/modifying columns that would make it differ from B). How can this be achieved?

My guess is with *a kind of trigger* on ALTER (though triggers happen only on CRUD) or *a special constraint* on A ? (though a Foreign Key on every column seems like an overkill).

(the use case: B is like a shadow of A, it will periodically receive a dump of A's records, so we want to be sure that if the structure of A changes we don't forget to change B accordingly)

Comment: [Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-inherit.html)

Comment: Maybe an [event trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html)?

Comment: thanks @Abelisto, that's the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abelisto is right in his comment, a good way to implement this in PostgreSQL is using [Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-inherit.html).

Another way is having a master a table and an ["updatable VIEW"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createview.html) (or a view with [RULEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createrule.html)...)

Answer (score 0):

As you already know triggers are in CRUD. I think maybe you can create a trigger where you compare both table on each CRUD and raise an alarm.  But that only will alert after the change was made and someone play with tableA.

You can create multiple FK for each tableB columns to tableA columns, but that only will inform if you try to delete or rename a columns, If you change field type or add new columns you wont get the alarm.